# Hex string to unicode (Chinese or other language) C#

Tags: c#

I can use UTF8 to convert
But when I test Unicode, some characters will be lost, whether I have set errors

Please give me some advice

Chinese = "对我很有帮助"
Lost display: "?我很有帮?"

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String hex2 = "F95B1162885F09672E5EA9522100";
            String temp3 = Trans2(hex2);
            Console.WriteLine(temp3);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static string Trans(String input)
        {
            string temp1 = ConvertHexToString(input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            return temp1;

        }


        private static string ConvertHexToString(String hexInput, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
        {
            int numberChars = hexInput.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
            {
                bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexInput.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            }
            return encoding.GetString(bytes);
        }
```

Comment: You should provide your actual code... why am I forced to convert so many things in your code from upper case to lower case (`Public`, `Int` etc.)

Comment: Also please be specific where the *"Lost display"* appears - the string looks fine in debug view.

Comment: Sorry! Update the new code!Please give some advice!

Comment: For me it looks like total crap with `Encoding.UTF8`, it was way better with `Encoding.Unicode` - are you sure your hex input is correct UTF8? Anyway, with Unicode I get the chinese symbols in Debugger View, but only `??????!` in the console, because the console with my font and language settings is completely incapable of chinese characters - you have to focus on your console more than your application I guess.

Comment: Your first character is meant to be U+5BF9, which has a UTF-8 encoding of E5 AF B9, which is nothing like the hex in your question... in general, the hex you've provided doesn't look like it should match the characters you've provided. It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] with specific sample input and expected output, rather than effectively two different examples.

Comment: I Change the console type ,then it is work! But I want to use Dll pass Data! How can i change the out put type (Unicode)

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code but can't replicate your issue. It looks all fine on my environment. However, I do agree @grek40 about console encoding, or look into the font used in your console - is it capable to display these characters?

My test code is below, on a GUI application, probably you can try it out:

```
private static string ConvertHexToString(String hexInput, System.Text.Encoding encoding) {
    int numberChars = hexInput.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2) {
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexInput.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return encoding.GetString(bytes);
}

private static string ConvertStringToHex(String strInput, System.Text.Encoding encoding) {
    return BitConverter.ToString(encoding.GetBytes(strInput)).Replace("-", String.Empty);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string strTest = "对我很有帮助!";
    Debug.Print(strTest);

    string hex;

    hex = ConvertStringToHex(strTest, Encoding.UTF8);
    Debug.Print(hex);
    Debug.Print(ConvertHexToString(hex, Encoding.UTF8));

    hex = ConvertStringToHex(strTest, Encoding.Unicode);
    Debug.Print(hex);
    Debug.Print(ConvertHexToString(hex, Encoding.Unicode));

    Debug.Print(ConvertHexToString("F95B1162885F09672E5EA9522100", Encoding.Unicode));
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
对我很有帮助!
E5AFB9E68891E5BE88E69C89E5B8AEE58AA921
对我很有帮助!
F95B1162885F09672E5EA9522100
对我很有帮助!
对我很有帮助!
```

Apparently your hex string in sample code is in Unicode format.

PS: If your input is read from file, you need to think about if the file is encoded in big/small endian and whether BOM is used.

Comment: *"Apparently your hex string in sample code is in UTF8 format"* how so? I think your example shows pretty clearly, that the question hex string matches the `Unicode` rather than `UTF8`.

Comment: @grek40 Sorry, it was a typo... Revised!